# Flutter - how create Card with label in left top?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to create something like this:

[image]

But I don’t know how to create a rounded label(green) that matches the card.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
SizedBox(
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  child: Card(
    elevation: 12,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
    child: Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Align(
          child: Image.asset(
            "your_image",
            width: 150,
            height: 100,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 0,
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 4, horizontal: 6),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.green,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(8),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(8),
                ) // green shaped
            ),
            child: Text("CHOCOLATE"),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Stack` widget, and add your card inside it.

Now use below code to add your `green` view

```
Positioned(
  left: 0.0,
  top: 0.0,
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.green,
    height: 150.0,
    width: 150.0,
  ),
)
```

Now use below pattern for rounded corner of `green` widget.
[image]

> Reference from [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-stack-in-flutter-3264619b3a77) and [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/clipping-in-flutter-e9eaa6b1721a)